# SP returning matches when condition specifies not to

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2012

My SP is supposed to only return records where the field GTid1 <> Gtid2. However, when i run this sp and then load my report in Visual Studio 
Below is the SQL in the SP used to extract the data i need for this report. It should return data where the LEI1 has matched LEI 2 but GTID1 <> GTID2

Example :

GTID1 = G0101    LEI: E12345     GTID2: G0201   LEI: E12345

```
 select  distinct
    @reportIdLeiDuplicates,
    wp1.CrmPartyId,
    wp1.GtId,  
    convert(varchar(20), 
            hashbytes('SHA1', isnull(wp1.CrmPartyId, '') + isnull(wp1.GtId, '') ),  
            2), 
    (select AttributeId from REPORTING.Attribute where Name = 'GT ID'),                     @WeccoSysId,        wp1.GtId,
    (select AttributeId from REPORTING.Attribute where Name = 'CRM Party Id'),              @WeccoSysId,        wp1.CrmPartyId,
    (select AttributeId from REPORTING.Attribute where Name = 'Legal Name'),                @WeccoSysId,        wp1.LegalName,
    (select AttributeId from REPORTING.Attribute where Name = 'Business Class'),            @WeccoSysId,        wp1.BusinessClass,
    (select AttributeId from REPORTING.Attribute where Name = 'Relationship Manager Name'), @WeccoSysId,        wp1.RmFullName,     
    (select AttributeId from REPORTING.Attribute where Name = 'PbeName'),                   @WeccoSysId,        wp1.PbeFullName,            
    (select AttributeId from REPORTING.Attribute where Name = 'Overall Status'),            @WeccoSysId,        wp1.OverallStatus,
    (select AttributeId from REPORTING.Attribute where Name = 'LEI'),                       
[![enter image description here][1]][1]@WeccoSysId,     wp1.Lei,
    (select AttributeId from REPORTING.Attribute where Name = 'GT ID'),                     
 @WeccoSysId,       wp2.GtId,
    (select AttributeId from REPORTING.Attribute where Name = 'CRM Party Id'),              @WeccoSysId,        wp2.CrmPartyId,
    (select AttributeId from REPORTING.Attribute where Name = 'Legal Name'),                
 @WeccoSysId,       wp2.LegalName,
    (select AttributeId from REPORTING.Attribute where Name = 'Business 
 Class'),           @WeccoSysId,        wp2.BusinessClass,
    (select AttributeId from REPORTING.Attribute where Name = 'Relationship 
   Manager Name'), @WeccoSysId,        wp2.RmFullName,      
    (select AttributeId from REPORTING.Attribute where Name = 'PbeName'),                   
       @WeccoSysId,     wp2.PbeFullName,            
    (select AttributeId from REPORTING.Attribute where Name = 'Overall 
 Status'),          @WeccoSysId,        wp2.OverallStatus,
    (select AttributeId from REPORTING.Attribute where Name = 'LEI'),                       
     @WeccoSysId,       wp2.Lei

 from       core.WeccoParty         wp1
 join   CORE.WeccoParty wp2                      on  wp1.Lei  = wp2.Lei
  where wp1.Lei                                   is not null
                                             and wp1.GtId < wp2.GtId
                                             and wp2.Lei is not null
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images. Consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve first.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: SQL server Management Studio

Comment: have shows example of what i am expecting to see